# Vídeo en java como mensaje emergente

Tags: java, video

Seguro que todos recordareis la mítica escena de Parque Jurásico en la que se aparecía la animación de *"no has dicho la palabra mágica"* me estoy proponiendo hacer algo parecido en java a modo de prueba pero no se como llamar a mi vídeo ( almacenado en el propio pc).

El código sería el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Introduce una clave maestra");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String masterclave=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Intruduce una clave");
    String clave=sc.next();

    if(clave.compareTo(masterclave)==0){
         System.out.println("Clave correcta");
    }
    else {
         System.out.println("VIDEO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mírate alguna **API** y busca sobre manejo de vídeos o archivos. El código por lo que has definido no es complicado. Si es un proyecto tuyo, busca sobre eso. Necesitas saber como mostrar un vídeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con este código:

```
try{ 
      Runtime run  = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
      Process proc = run.exec("start C:\\video.mp4");
    }
    catch (IOException e){ 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Tal vez te pueda servir.

Comment: No sé si estoy poniendo la ruta correctamente, lo tengo exactamente en esta ruta A:\Java\test\src <br/> Por tanto ¿Sería correcto ("start A:\\Java\\test\\src\\magicMouseScroll.mp4"); ?

Comment: Sí, así debe estar.